# IdentityServer3 in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, identityserver3

I've just deployed my IdentityServer3 solution out to an AWS instance. I had IdentityServer3 configured to RequireSSL. The problem seems that it's relatively common to have SSL running up to the AWS load balancer, then run non-SSL between the LB and IIS. So, I set RequireSSL to false and tried again. Now the problem seems to be that when IdentityServer tries to redirect to the sign-in page, it does so without https. When this redirect exits and re-enters through the LB, it fails because it must be https coming into the LB. So, it seems that IdentityServer is constructing the redirect to the sign-in page with consideration of the RequireSSL flag. Is there anyway around this? I'm working with my ops guy to just run SSL all the way to IIS, but i'm getting some pushback (of course).

Answer (score 1):

As the docs state here:

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/deployment.html

If you want to terminate SSL on the load balancer, there are two relevant settings on the options:

RequireSsl
Set this to false to allow non-SSL connections between the load balancer and IdentityServer.

PublicOrigin
Since your internal farm nodes have different names than the public reachable address, IdentityServer can’t use it for link generation. Set this property to the public name.

Comment: I have WebAPI that is exposed and except jwt token ,then web api will validate token from identity server which is behind load balancer , so how we can test that webAPI able to communicate with Identity server using http and not https connection as both are in web farm and behind a firewall.